# Matlab: Visualizing multi-dimensional structures in the Workspace

Tags: matlab

I have a structure (struct variable) containing several fields such as name, age, height, etc. I used to only have two indices into this variable: the person's ID number and an experimental condition. This way, I could easily visualise the variable for debug purposes: double-clicking on it in the Workspace gave me first the 2D matrix determined by the indices, and once I clicked on a cell in the matrix I got the corresponding fields of the selected structure.

Now I needed to add one more parameter as an index into the struct, which has therefore become 3D. Visualising it is no longer possible, as the Workspace just shows it as a "4x2x9 struct with 5 fields" but doesn't let me select an index triplet and dig deeper into it. The only way I can peek into the contents is by looking at a specific index combination in the command prompt, e.g. "M(i1,i2,i3).name", but this doesn't give me the overview I wanted.

Can anyone suggest a workaround so that I can visualise the overall contents of the struct variable? Perhaps by first choosing a value for the first index, and then seeing the struct matrix corresponding to the remaining 2 dimensions?

Hopefully my description makes sense, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualizing in the variable editor will not be possible as it is 3D, but you can print it in the workspace with e.g.:

```
M.name
```

or, if you want to look at only one index k of your new variable:

```
M(:,:,k).name
```

You could also consider to use one structure instead of a structure array, where each field contains an array indexed with your variables. This would allow you to do:

```
M.name(i,j,k)
```

or

```
M.name(:,:,:)
```

and preserves the structure of your data when you print it.